# converting multiple rows into a single row based on specific conditions

Tags: r

Can you please suggest how to implement the following in R.

I have a table as given below.

```
 ID  object  value
  1   a  3
  2   a  2
  3   b  3
  4   a  1
  5   a  2
  6   b  2
  7   a  1
  8   b  1
```

I would like to get the following table

```
 ID object values
 1   a    3, 2, 1
 2   a    2, 1
 4   a    1
 5   a    2, 1
 7   a    1
 3   b    3, 2, 1
 6   b    2,1
 8   b    1
```

In other words, for each object each row value is appended with the next observed values till the value reaches 1.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Bikas

Comment: Suppose for the 2nd row, `value` is 4.  What would be the result?  I didn't read the last line before I posted the solution.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, the output should be ID object values
 1   a    3, 4, 1
 2   a    4, 1
 4   a    1
 5   a    2, 1
 7   a    1
 3   b    3, 2, 1
 6   b    2,1
 8   b    1

Comment: Your new request is not very clear. Suppose if it ends on `2` instead of `1`.  What will happen to the row 4 where the value is `1`? Or did you mean that you don't have any `1` there, but the `min` value is `2` in the dataset?

Comment: Anyway I updated. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a modified `dataset` with 2nd row value as `4`

```
res <-  unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$object), function(x) {
                     x$value <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) {
                                   i1 <- i:nrow(x)
                                   indx <- which(x$value[i1]==1)[1]
                                   paste(x$value[i1[seq(indx)]], collapse=",")
                                       })
                                     x}),
                                  df$object)  


    res[order(res$object),]
    #  ID object   value
    #1  1      a 3, 4, 1
    #2  2      a    4, 1
    #4  4      a       1
    #5  5      a    2, 1
    #7  7      a       1
    #3  3      b 3, 2, 1
    #6  6      b    2, 1
    #8  8      b       1
```

Also, using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, N:=1:.N, by=object][,
          values:=unlist(lapply(N, function(i) {
                                   val <- value[i:.N]
                                   paste(val[1:which(val==1)[1]], collapse=",")
                                  })), keyby=object][,-(3:4), with=FALSE]


   #    ID object values
   #1:  1      a  3,4,1
   #2:  2      a    4,1
   #3:  4      a      1
   #4:  5      a    2,1
   #5:  7      a      1
   #6:  3      b  3,2,1
   #7:  6      b    2,1
   #8:  8      b      1
```

#### Update

If you need the sequence up till the minimum `value`, you could replace `which(x$value[i1]==1` to `which(x$value[i1]==min(x$value))[1]`.  For example, using the first code as a function.

```
 f1 <- function(dat){
   lst <- split(dat, dat$object)
   lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
        x$value <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) {
                     i1 <- i:nrow(x)
                     indx <- which(x$value[i1]== min(x$value))[1]
                     paste(x$value[i1[seq(indx)]], collapse=",")
                        })
                       x})
   res <- unsplit(lst2, dat$object)
   res[order(res$object),] 
  } 

  f1(df)
  #   ID object value
  #1  1      a 3,4,1
  #2  2      a   4,1
  #4  4      a     1
  #5  5      a   2,1
  #7  7      a     1
  #3  3      b 3,2,1
  #6  6      b   2,1
  #8  8      b     1
```

If I change all the `1` values to `2`

```
  df$value[df$value==1] <- 2
  f1(df)
  #  ID object value
  #1  1      a 3,4,2
  #2  2      a   4,2
  #4  4      a     2
  #5  5      a     2
  #7  7      a     2
  #3  3      b   3,2
  #6  6      b     2
  #8  8      b     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, object = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", 
"b", "a", "b"), value = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"object", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. If the last entry for an object is not 1 but something else (say 2 and the last values are 4, 3, 2) and I want the sequence till the last entry (in this case, something like 3,4,2 and 4,2), how can the code be modified?

Answer (score 0):

It is not altogether clear whether

- the data will always be ordered decreasing by value
- and whether the values should be output in decreasing order

IN any event, I would use the `data.table` library.  Assuming your table is a data.frame, `df`, I would do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ values >= 1 ][ by=list( ID, value ), order(value, decreasing=TRUE),  values = paste0( value, sep=", " ) ]
```

What this is doing is:

- initializing your data.frame as a data.table
- using only rows with values >= 1
- ordering the data
- grouping by ID and value
- pasting value together

Comment: Thanks. Since the initial table has colname as value, I guess the selection criterion should be value>=1. However, after correcting that, I am still getting the following syntax error: unused argument(s) (values = paste0(value, sep = ","))

Comment: I personally find it a bit confusing to have the `by=` at the start, given that data.frames have i, j as the first and second argument as well. It's easier to understand data.tables are similar, with the extra flexibility of `by` argument.